# AUTOHOTKEY - how to send control K with joystick

Tags: autohotkey, send, ctrl

i cant seem to get the syntax for autohotkey to work in a script that I want to send the following inputs to my game with joystick

```
Joy7::send {^1}
Joy8::send {^k}
Joy13::send {^u}
```

i have tried the follwing:

```
Joy8::send {Control k}
Joy8::send {Ctrl k}
Joy8::sendinput {Control k}
Joy8::send ^{k}
Joy8::sendinput ^{k}
```

nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

There are several potential points of failure for what you're trying to do: having the right key code, sending the right thing, and having the program accept the sent keys.

My guess is that you've already correctly determined your Joy8 and whatnot.

In terms of sending the right thing I have found that some places respond better to {Ctrl Down}k{Ctrl Up} than to the methods you've listed, so you might try that and see if it works.

Finally some games do a pretty good job of stopping Autohotkey from interacting with them, in which case it may be extremely difficult to do. You may have already looked [at this AHK in games guide](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/111737-how-to-make-ahk-work-in-most-games-the-basics/) but if you haven't it may be useful.

Also in terms of troubleshooting, does a new tab open with Joy8::Send, ^t in a web browser?

Staggering inputs may also help:

```
Joy8::
Send, {Ctrl Down}
Sleep, 5
Send, {k down}
Sleep, 5
Send, {k up}
Sleep, 5
Send, {Ctrl up}
```

Comment: heres the situation. Im using what is called a trainer, which is an exe that sends data to the memory of the game that is running. This trainer uses the keyboard for input. I press Ctrl K on the keyboard and the trainer performs the action it is supposed to. I thought that using Autohotkey was simply emulating keystrokes, which in this case I thought wasnt working due to syntax errors. If I knew the correct syntax I could troubleshoot from there, but im not even sure which one is correct.

Comment: {Ctrl Down}k{Ctrl Up} is this supposed to be in one line like this? To simplify this I took took the joystick out the code and I simply used the key 'e' like this: e::Send {Ctrl Down}k{Ctrl Up} but this did not work either.

Comment: So a few things that the forum page I linked mentioned that you might want to try: running the script as administrator and putting a very short sleep command between parts of the send (I'll edit my asnwer to include this code).

Comment: thanks for your help. It turns out the application I was trying to send keystrokes wasnt able to receive them without some modifications. The author of the program has fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: That's fortunate! Glad you're able to send those inputs now :)